# Is there a perl module that can automatically login to most websites given user/pass?

Tags: perl

Anyone knows such a module?

Though I guess it should be based on `Expect`?

Comment: The only reason I can imagine for a tool like that would be for something like comment spam so you might want to clarify or face a deluge of downvotes. [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize) and related packages would be the place to look, in any case, not [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Expect), which is shell-centric.

Comment: @Ashley there are thousands of reasons apart from spamming one would want to log into a website programmatically. For example, to regularly email yourself some information that is only available after logging into a website.

Comment: @Will Sheppard, thousands? There is a handful of valid reasons to have a script that can log into *a* website and even of those, many websites prohibit automation in their terms of service. To have a script that can arbitrarily log into "most websites" strongly suggests to me spamming or data mining. I did give a good faith suggestion, of Mech, with my request for clarification. None has appeared.

Answer (score 5):

[`WWW::Mechanize`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize) has methods which could be of help. However, it has to be instructed on which form it is to submit with the login credentials. Have a look at its [`submit_form`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize#%24mech-%3Esubmit_form%28_..._%29) method.

Comment: Yes, WWW::Mechanize is the way to go. You can work out how the script should go by using [WWW::Mechanize::Shell](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize::Shell)